# how to make enter on input show up on output

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

When the user presses enter in the input box I would like that to reflect in the H1 tag.

As you can see when the user types 
Line 1
they can press enter and create
line 2 in the input no problem, but the output in the h1 tag is still "Line 1 line 2" all on one line.

Please look at the fiddle as that will make a lot more sense.

I was thinking about using a keypress function to get when the user presses enter and then do something with that? I'm not sure if there is a better way though.

https://jsfiddle.net/BSmyth634/ovz8thrp/

```
<div ng-app>
   <form>
     <textarea rows="4" type="text" ng-model="todoText" size="30" placeholder="add new todo here">
     </textarea>
   </form>
   <h1>
    {{todoText || 'Hello World'}}
   </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: You basically want to change `\n` into a `<br/>`, see the duplicate questions above. You can do this with filter(s) or you can use `white-space: pre` in CSS.

Comment: Please specify this is an AngularJS question... tags are not sufficient.

Comment: @Loenix They did, the tag `angularjs` is AngularJS.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `style="white-space: pre;"` in your code to do it.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ovz8thrp/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways to achieve what you want.

- Use `white-space` css property. In your case the `pre-line` value might be interesting.
- Create Angular's [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) and use it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use pre element instead of h1

```
<pre>{{todoText || 'Hello World'}}</pre>
```

or use this

```
<h1 ng-repeat="line in todoText.split('\n')">
    {{line}}
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Jquery approach**

```
$("textarea").on('keypress',function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        $('h1').html($("textarea").val())
    }

})
```

Comment: `ng-model` already does this in angular, it's a two-way data-binding. This also won't solve OP's problem.